# k-query oracle Turing machine

Tags: complexity-theory

A k-query oracle Turing machine can query its oracle for at most $k$ times. How could I show that assuming $\text{NP} \not= \text{coNP}$, we have $\text{NP} \cup \text{coNP} \subsetneq \text{P}^{\text{SAT},1}$ (query only once)? I tried to show this strict inclusion directly or its counterexample but to no avail... There was such a question on this site, but the top vote isn't a direct answer. Could somebody provide me more insight into this again? Thanks!

More specifically, I wonder how should I think of these $k$-query machines from machines with unlimited number of queries. I can see that they should have limited computation power, but I'm not sure how to utilize that for the proof.

Comment: Hint: there is a very simple way to construct a problem which is both NP-hard and coNP-hard.

Comment: So any PSPACE-complete problem like TQBF will work, since NP and coNP are in PSPACE so the languages inside reduce to it?

Comment: No, TQBF almost surely doesn't lie in $P^{SAT,1}$. What I mean is that given two complexity classes $C_1,C_2$ and languages $L_1,L_2$ such that $L_1$ is $C_1$-hard and $L_2$ is $C_2$-hard, you can construct a language which is both $C_1$-hard and $C_2$-hard.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, that's kind of what I tried to do but didn't quite figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to show the contrapositive. Since $\mathsf{NP} \cup \mathsf{coNP} \subseteq \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{SAT},1}$, the contrapositive states that if $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{SAT},1} \subseteq \mathsf{NP} \cup \mathsf{coNP}$ then $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{coNP}$. Let us assume, therefore, that every problem in $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{SAT},1}$ is both in $\mathsf{NP}$ and in $\mathsf{coNP}$. We would like to show that this implies that $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{coNP}$.

We can imagine that the argument will have the following structure:

1. Come up with some language $L \in \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{SAT},1}$.
2. The assumption implies that $L \in \mathsf{NP}$ or $L \in \mathsf{coNP}$.
3. Use these facts to say something about the relation between $\mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{coNP}$.

Our goal is to show that $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{coNP}$, or equivalently $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{coNP}$. This, in turn, is equivalent to showing that $\mathsf{SAT} \in \mathsf{coNP}$. Considering the plan above, what we need is to find a language $L \in \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{SAT},1}$ such that both $L \in \mathsf{NP}$ and $L \in \mathsf{coNP}$ imply $\mathsf{SAT} \in \mathsf{coNP}$.

We can take as $L$ the following language:
$$
L = \{(x,0) : x \in \mathsf{SAT}\} \cup \{(x,1) : x \notin \mathsf{SAT}\}.
$$
Details left to you.

Comment: Er, I’m not super familiar with complexity theory, but doesnt $$A \subseteq B \cup C$$ only imply that elements in A are in at least one of B or C, but not necessarily both?

Comment: Right, thanks. Let me modify the proof.

Comment: Indeed, this makes it a bit harder to demystify the proof.

Comment: That's an interesting language! I remembered using a similar trick to construct a language neither Turing recognizable nor co-Turing recognizable...Is there a name for this disjoint union trick, and how does it work in general?

Comment: Sometimes this kind of combination is denoted by $\oplus$. So $L = \mathsf{SAT}\oplus\mathsf{coSAT}$.

Comment: So I think that $L$ is both NP and co-NP hard because we can reduce any instance of an NP or co-NP problem to the boolean satisfiability formula first in polynomial time, then attach any second coordinate (0 or 1). Then by assumption $L$ is both NP and co-NP complete. But then $SAT$ (in NP) is reducible to $L$ (NP-complete), which is reducible to $\overline{SAT}$ (coNP-complete). Hence $SAT$ must be in co-NP?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks, that's the first time I saw that notation in CS.. :( By the way, I'm using Sipser's textbook and is now finishing a majority of the problems in the latter chapters on complexity theory, but I still find it hard to summarize general strategies for dealing with the less trivial problems, except by remembering all the "tricks". Is there any other textbooks with also very good exercises and perhaps more explanation that can help me better synthesize what I have learned?

Comment: This notation isn’t that common, so it’s not surprising you’ve never seen it.

Comment: I see. Also, could you kindly confirm if my reasoning above makes sense or not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should be able to recognize whether an argument is mathematically valid or not. You won’t get far without this ability.

Comment: I think I didn't explain before why $L$ is in *both* NP and co-NP, when the assumption only implies it is in at least one. But suppose $L$ is in NP, then its complement, which is isomorphic to itself, should also be in NP, so $L$ is in co-NP. Similarly if we assume it's in co-NP then we get it's in NP as well. Now I think it makes more sense to me...since I have used the structure of $L$ in the proof. Still some critique will be appreciated as I don't want to walk away believing in a fallacious proof on my part.

Comment: The best critique is self-critique.